# search result criteria

Tags: search

I've hooked up search and if I run a query on 'Second Presbyterian' for example, I get the expected return.

However, if I search for 'Second Pres' I get nothing coming back as a partial match.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Searching](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching) article in the Docs. If you want to list all entries containing a word that begins with "Second Pres", you have to use this search term "Second Pres*".